# Creating a pick a number code

Tags: c

I am not the best at C yet, but I was creating a code that will allow the user to pick a number from 1 to 10. If the number isn't in range, it will prompt an error . I was using a do-while statements, and somehow I am receiving an error when the number is at range. If successful, the user will receive see number printed at the screen in chronological order example: 7 is in range so it will print 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. The code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number;


    do
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        printf("Error: number not in range (1-10). Try again: \n");
    }
    while(number == 0.0||number<1||number>10);

       {printf("you win\n");}


    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate a tip that I could make it.

Comment: `printf("Error: number not in range (1-10). Try again: \n");` This statement is gonna execute irrespective of the fact that the number lies within the range or not. Also, why `number == 0.0` instead of `number == 0`

Comment: When is a number that satisfies `number == 0.0` not also a number that satisfies `number < 1`?  In other words, the equality condition is superfluous.  It's also odd because you force the compiler to convert the `int` to a `double` to compare with `0.0`.  You should check the return value from `scanf()` — you could end up with an infinite loop if the user types `bother` instead of a number in the range 1..10.

Comment: That was a typo. I re-edited the code before posting and I not see that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `if` statement inside the loop as well for displaying the message. After picking a number, the `printf` still gets to go through and that's why you're seeing that message.

For the second part of your question, displaying numbers until the selected number, a simple for loop will suffice. Your condition to stop will depend on the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as you are printing the Error message before checking the condition in while loop

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     int main()
     {
       int number;
        do
         {
           printf("Enter a number: ");
           scanf("%d", &number);
           if(number<1 ||number >10))
            printf("Error: number not in range (1-10). Try again: \n");
        }
        while(number == 0.0||number<1||number>10);
         printf("you win\n");
      return 0;
}
```